# Kubernetes with Istio: Authenticate with External Oauth Service

Tags: kubernetes, oauth, oauth-2.0, istio

I'm looking for a way to authenticate an Istio-enabled Kubernetes cluster with an external Oauth2 provider.  The Nginx Ingress controller has a way to do this when using vanilla Ingres resources.

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/auth/oauth-external-auth/

However, I'm not sure how to do this with Istio Gateway and VirtualService objects. Basically, I need to be able to provide an auth-url and an auth-sigin url to Istio, so it will authenticate the same way that the oauth Nginx ingress controller does. I've found a few examples of EnvoyFilters suggest ways to do this, but there isn't a lot of documentation on how to make this work.

Any advice to get Istio to integrate with an external Oauth would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just a thought..you can use istio without the istio provided ingress gateway and use Nginx as your ingress

Comment: Thank you @ArghyaSadhu  for you suggestion on this. Do you know of any resources on how I might do this? Also, my use-case for Istio is so that I can direct traffic using DestinationRules. Is that still possible if using the Nginx Ingress?

Answer (score 2):

OriginAuthenticationMethod is the authentication policy that you are looking for.

Refer: https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/security/istio.authentication.v1alpha1/#OriginAuthenticationMethod

> Currently, only JWT is supported for origin authentication.

A workaround would be using another type of Ingress.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @tummala-dhanvi. With the JWT method, my understanding is that every web request needs to contain a JWT token that would get validated. However, I'm wondering how that would work with a bunch of web-services that are to be normally accessed by a web browser? Does that mean that a visitor would need to install a browser plugin to inject the JWT token on every request? Regarding the other types of ingress methods, if you know anything about how to integrate Istio DestinationRules with the Nginx Ingress, I'd be really interested to hear about it.

Comment: https://discuss.istio.io/t/istio-without-gateway-with-nginx-ingress/593 for istio and nginx-ingress

Comment: JWT doesn't make sense for end-user to inject it (client-side), it should be handled by your frontend service. (for example javascript express)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. I was hoping that wouldn't require injecting something via javascript, but I understand that this is the only option right now. As an update, I was having some luck getting an EnvoyFilter sitting in front of the Istio Gateway to work for this problem, but that required learning Lua. (Not quite plug and play :-)

Comment: do you know know if you can use the JWT token with a cookie instead of an Authorization header?